# How to change the highlight color of a textbox in vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net-2010

Is it possible to change the highlight color of a textbox in vb.net. I want to replace lightblue to some other color with white color text. Any idea please?

Comment: You can set the [SelectionBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.selectionbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) for the highlight color

Comment: In windows forms apps highlight color is determined by the system settings. SelectionBrush works with WPF apps only.

Comment: Any Windows API to do this in Windows form apps? I use my custom theme for my windows app. I can apply the color matching for comboboxes, menus in my app, but, not possible the same for Text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Work with a richtextbox instead, the layout looks the same.